# Processing a text file from PL/SQL vs Java

Tags: java, performance, oracle, stored-procedures

I need to implement a store procedure in an Oracle database that will do the following:

- Read an external file that needs to be processed (extract data from file and validate)
- Call another store procedure in the database in charge to validate/insert the data.
- Manage exceptions.
- Write to another file with the results of the operations executed.

I know I can do all these things with PL/SQL or Java (store procedure), but which will be more efficient/faster or better? most of the operations are reading/writing a file, and the database operations are done in a store procedure already.

I have read other posts about PL/SQL vs Java (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821841/java-stored-procedure-vs-pl-sql-stored-procedure) and [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/550834/Oracle-OAS/Native-Java-Oracle-vs-PL)) but none talks about this.

Comment: Have you evaluated external tables for this operation? While I remain opposed to this design, that might be one of the less grotesque ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would never want to use a SQL dialect, no matter how versatile it may be, to do anything outside the DB.  I would do what you're trying to do preferably in a shell or perl script, to use the lowest common denominator, although Java is OK, just perhaps a bit too sophisticated for a job this simple. But if Java is all you have or know how to use, then go for it.

Comment: I agree, though I must point out that the question is about using PL/SQL to parse the data or a Java *stored procedure* to parse the data. He seems intent on using Oracle to do the parsing either way.

Comment: what's a "Java stored procedure"?  last time i checked, stored procedures were db constructs...  you can call it from Java, that doesn't make it a "Java stored procedure"

Comment: Oracle supports [writing stored procedures in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm).

Comment: seems like a clusterf..k to me.  rather keep it clean

Comment: I agree, but again, that's not what the question is about. He wants his database to parse text files.

Comment: yes, that's right, the database will be doing the parsing one way or another. It's just the way the business wants it. So the answer will be the same?